# render js file from other link using node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have a html file that include a form. when I click a submit button it goes to app.js file. home page is rendered from app.js file too. it render index.ejs file.

```html
<form  action="/write" method="POST">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info float-left " value="save">
</form>
```

`app.js`:

```js
app.post('/write', function(req, res) {
    //... save something to database
}
```

I want that after it finished saving it goes to home page that rendered from index.ejs file using code :

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // ...
    res.render('index.ejs', { users: result });
});
```

but the problem is that in this part how can I render index.ejs in address "/":

```js
app.post('/write', function(req, res) {
    // save some thing in database
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual behavior is to redirect the user to another page after making POST request with form data. You can achieve this using the following code:

```
app.post('/write', function(req, res) {
    // save something to database
    res.redirect('/');
}
```